# How to download android things OS source code?

Tags: android, iot, android-things, git-repo

I could find git repository/branch for Brillio but no separate for Android things. 
Is it that it is not open source yet or released for public ?

Comment: I have the same question. so, Android things is still closed source now, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No because AndroidThings is still in preview as you can see from this link:

https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html

the source code is not available.

There is a GitHub page though with the examples of how things are built on Android Things:

https://github.com/androidthings

Answer (score 11):

```
cd ~
mkdir IOT
cd IOT
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-o-iot-preview-5
repo sync
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image file by:

1. Go to [Android Things console](https://partner.android.com/things/console/) and login.
2. Create/Open a product.
3. In the "Factory Images" section click on "Create Build Configuration".
4. Download the image file of your product containing Android Things.

Comment: The image does not contain the source

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like it won't be open-source at all.

From an [Ars Technica article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/05/android-things-hits-version-1-0-with-centralized-google-update-system/?comments=1):

> Just like Windows, Android Things is closed source and has a centralized update system.