# GSM/GPRS Module native integration on Raspberry 3 with Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, iot, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I would like to know if there is any way to make a GPRS / GSM module (SIM800L) as a "default" connection in android things that allows browsing the internet and making requests using the Android libraries.

Comment: If you can connect that GSM module to an Android Things device, I guess that it will take that connection if nothing else is configured, you may need to write a driver, but it seems doable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems no, because as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648692/6950238) answer of [Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413127/blundell) described: the source code is not available for Developer Preview. But You can use UART and AT commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. I have been able to integrate SIM800L TO RPI3 running Android Things via UART and AT commands. I am however using it for sending SMS and not for Internet connectivity. I do not see an issue in achieving that as well.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: So this would not work with an NXP Pico running Android Things?