# Internet for Raspberry Pi 3 running on Android Things via a GSM modem

Tags: gsm, android-things

Has anyone figured a way of installing PPPD or something similar in order to have an active internet connection via a GSM modem on a Raspberry Pi 3 running on Android Things DP5?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSM/GPRS Module native integration on Raspberry 3 with Android Things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917648/gsm-gprs-module-native-integration-on-raspberry-3-with-android-things)

Comment: I was referring to a USB dongle, as you mentioned in the answer below and a new DP was released after the previous question had been published. It is in essence similar, indeed. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems [DP5](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#developer_preview_5) of Android Things still didn't support Internet connections via  USB modem dongles (and it's impossible to add support manually, because as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648692/6950238) answer of [Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413127/blundell) described: the source code is not available for Developer Preview). But You can use [UART](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback) and AT commands like `AT+SAPBR`.