# Connect internet using gsm/3g/4g with raspberry pi running android things?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, iot, android-things

Can someone tell me how can I connect my `raspberry pi` running `android things` using mobile sim/3g/4g data with internet? I want to use my android things in remote areas where there are no `Wi-Fi`. I want to know about the hardware details as well. Which `modem` to use and connect with `raspberry pi` in order to use internet connectivity from mobile `sim`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet for Raspberry Pi 3 running on Android Things via a GSM modem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856198/internet-for-raspberry-pi-3-running-on-android-things-via-a-gsm-modem)

Comment: That answer doesn't explain much, can you provide a better link??

Comment: It depends what you module want to use: you need shield like [this](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/3g-gprs-shield-for-arduino-3g-gps) and use shield module AT-command set to establish and manage 3G connection and data transfer. Different modules use different AT-command sets.

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate, both in the sense that the question is the same, and in that the answer there explains that there is no elegant solution *and* proposes a workaround.  The sub question of which device to buy is a "shopping question" which is off topic through most of the Stack Exchange system with the possible exception of Hardware Recommendations SE.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to buy 3G/4G modules. There are many vendors such as Telit, Ublox or Sierra Wireless.

Comment: The framework does not have support for Internet connectivity through a cell network module right now.

Comment: I am thinking of doing it via AT commands, ditching the framework?

Comment: @TayWeeWen while talking directly to the module from a unique app could be a possibility, the current text of your answer simply saying to buy a module is just a restatement of the most obvious part of the question, and neither helpful nor in any practical sense an answer.