# If Android Things OS designed for open source?

Tags: android-things

I cannot find the Android Things OS source code.
If Android Things designed for open source, even in the future ?
Or the OS is managed by Google only and not for open source ?

I do not want the way to download the source code. This question aimed for some ideas from the design perspective

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download android things OS source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647543/how-to-download-android-things-os-source-code)

Comment: Thanks @Onik. Mine is different. I do not want the way to download the source code. This question aimed for some ideas from the design perspective.

Comment: Currently Android Things is in Developer Preview, so the code is not open sourced as things continue to change. Once a stable version is released, this may change.

Is there any questions you have from the design perspective related to its open source nature?

Comment: @Nick, Yes, more configuration for OS can be made for open source project.

Comment: @NickFelker will Android Things be open sourced after release? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like it won't be.

From an [Ars Technica article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/05/android-things-hits-version-1-0-with-centralized-google-update-system/?comments=1):

> Just like Windows, Android Things is closed source and has a centralized update system.