# Android things on non-supported platform

Tags: android-things

Does anyone know if it will be possible to port android things to other platforms. Right now it is very limited number of platforms supported and it would be great if we could use boards that use Snapdragon 410E ( DragonBoard 410c). I looked over internet but couldnt find anything relevant.

Comment: In general, it's possible: source code available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/) and you can download it like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787946/6950238) answer of [Zbigniew Mazur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7604485/zbigniew-mazur). But it's not trivial task.

Comment: Although it may be possible to port AOSP to other platforms, the Android Things Support Library is currently not open source, so it cannot be ported.

Comment: @NickFelker Is there a plan to make it open source in the future, so that community could make ports for Soc-s that are not supported currently

Comment: I am currently not sure what the long-term plans for the support library will be.

Comment: There is a standard Android 5.1 build for the DragonBoard 410C available along with Linux and Windows 10 IoT Core. Here is a link to the Android dowload for DragonBoard 410C from 96Boards https://www.96boards.org/documentation/consumer/dragonboard/dragonboard410c/downloads/android.md.html